# How to render multiple object elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

In react I have this

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> = React.createElement(
  HelloWorld,
  {
    description: this.properties.description
  }
);

ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);



const element2: React.ReactElement<ICalendarProps> = React.createElement(
  MyCalendar,
  {
    isMonthPickerVisible: true,
    dateRangeType: DateRangeType.Day,
    autoNavigateOnSelection: true,
    showGoToToday: true,
    showNavigateButtons: true,
    highlightCurrentMonth: true,
    highlightSelectedMonth: true,
    isDayPickerVisible: true,
    showMonthPickerAsOverlay: true,
    //showWeekNumbers: true,
    //minDate: new Date(),
    //maxDate: new Date(),
    //restrictedDates: [],
    //showSixWeeksByDefault: true,
    //workWeekDays: [DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday],
    //firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Monday,
}
);



ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
ReactDom.render(element2, this.domElement);
```

Only 1 shows though.

but how do I render them both?

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this snippet

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/hello-world

all your components should be under same ReactDOM